# how to connect newly created database in oracle

Tags: database, oracle10g, toad

I have currently Oracle 10g and toad installed on my machine. Since my initial installation does not support Turkish characters, I 've created a new database in Toad Editor, and a new user.How can I connect this newly created database? Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you have only one database on the machine and you are admin run `sqlplus / as sysdba` in the command prompt and create you'r self a dba user to work with.

Comment: 1- There is only one database 2- I am admin I run sql_plus / as sysdba. I select all tables via SELECT owner, table_name
  FROM dba_tables and tables from the old database is still appeared.

Comment: I think you are confused between a schema and a database, and for that matter - an instance. database is the software. instance is the memory allocated for the database operations. a user/schema is what you connect to and where you create your objects. to see your database query `v$database`, your instance `v$instance` and your users/schema's query `dba_users`.

Comment: However I deliberately choose creating a new database. How can I do this?

Comment: i'm not familiar with Toads wizards but again - i think you are mistaking an instance for a database. database is just the software. if you want to create a new instance on the same machine lunch `dbca` from the cmd and follow the wizard.